# Razor `if` does not register closing `}` if there is an opened `<table>` tag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor, html-table

This code, in a Razor view:

```
if (true)
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
}

...

if (true)
{
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

does not run. It claims that there is no closing `}` on the first `if()` statement, and I'm guessing it's because of the `<table>` tag.

Is there a way I can work around this to conditionally insert my `<table>` tags?

Comment: Does it work if you enclose the entire `<table>...</table>` inside a single if-statement? If so, you should change your code to that, instead. In what scenario would you want to conditionally print the table header and footer tags, but not conditionally print whatever's inside the table? Wouldn't you end up with random `<tr>` and `<td>` tags if the condition were false?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try prepending the tags with `@:`:

```
if (true)
{
    @:<table>
        @:<tbody>
}

...

if (true)
{
        @:</tbody>
    @:</table>
}
```

Comment: Why does razor auto-format put the end tags on a new line?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert it as strings, then they are not parsed as html and doesn't interfer with the syntax:

```
@Html.Raw(true?"<table><tbody>":"")

@Html.Raw(true?"</tbody></table>":"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Razor does expect the matching closing tags to be inside of the statement by default.

You can use the special `<text>` tag to help Razor out:

```
@if (true) {
    <text>
    <table>
        <tbody>
    </text>
}
```

Comment: Razor still complains with this because it recognizes `<table>` and `<tbody>` are HTML tags, and expects them to close before the `<text>` tag closes.

Comment: I'm using VS2012, MVC4 and it works for me. Are you using the same? In any case, you still get warnings about the closing tags, which is why I prefer D Stanley's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this doesn't prevent Razor from recognizing the `}`, but as you say, there are still warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using razor code blocks by enclosing the if blocks in a @{ } statement, or prepending the if with an @ such that it appears as @if:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx