# A proper way of using IF statements in Razor when opening html tags inside of it?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, .net-core

Hi I've been working on a ASP.NET browser based game **without any scripting**.
There is a problem though when I try to use IF ELSE in a Razor file to generate HTML tags.

Here is the code:

```
<table width="400" height="400 " style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; table-layout:fixed;" class="field">
    @for (var row = 0; row < Model.Field.RowCount; row++)
    {
        <tr>
            @for (var column = 0; column < Model.Field.ColumnCount; column++)
            {
                var tile = Model.Field;

                @if (tile.TileField[row, column].IsMarked)
                {
                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">
                }else{
                    <td style="border:2px solid black;">
                }
                    <a href='/Tetravex/Move?row=@(row)&column=@(column)'>
                        <table width="100" height="100" style="transform:rotate(45deg); text-align:center;">
                            <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
                                <td style="border-right:1px solid black; transform:rotate(-45deg);"><p style="margin:0px;">@(tile.TileField[row, column].North)</p></td>
                                <td style="transform:rotate(-45deg);"><p style="margin:0px;">@(tile.TileField[row, column].East)</p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-right:1px solid black; transform:rotate(-45deg);"><p style="margin:0px;">@(tile.TileField[row, column].West)</p></td>
                                <td style="transform:rotate(-45deg);"><p style="margin:0px;">@(tile.TileField[row, column].South)</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </a>
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

*I know the code isn't too clear, quite convoluted and there is probably a better way to do it, I'm just curious as to why this doesn't work. And don't worry about all the CSS properties rammed in there, I'll eventually clean that up.*

**The problem is** that Visual Studio doesn't like that the `<td>` tag isn't closed inside the `if` statement and because of that the `}else{` statement gets grayed out and ignored. Why is that?

Comment: Instead of an `if/else` at all you can just put the change in-line: `<td style="border:@(tile.TileField[row, column].IsMarked ? "1px" : "2px") solid black;">`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412818/

Comment: @David Damn that works alot better, thanks!